# PHP echo isn't firing, it's displaying plain text instead

Tags: php, echo

```
<input readonly type="text" name="newSubscription" id="newSubscription" class="print_input_class" value="<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>getMaterials();</script>;" ?>"><p></p>
```

Any ideas why instead of firing the javascript, it's printing the echo verbatim? THanks.

Comment: what are you trying to do man?? script inside input tag??

Comment: is this inside of a `.php` file? Note: servers by default don't parse `.html` files.

Comment: I want the value of the input box to be set to whatever the output of that function is, and yes it's a .php file.

Comment: and you have php installed and setup correctly?

Comment: @user790454 I'm sorry, but that was NOT enough. When I tried it, it printed "return getMaterials()" in the box. getMaterials should be returning either "yes" or "no"

Comment: assign value from javascript using input's id

Comment: Checked the browser's console for errors? What does this `getMaterials` function look like?

Comment: @j08691 The _printMaterialManager variable is set from a different .php page that gets passed to this one, but they both use the same javascript file so I don't see why the variable wouldn't persist.

`code`    function getMaterials() 
{
    msg = "";
    _printMaterialManagerType === true ? msg = "Yes" : msg = "No";
    return msg;
}          Sorry, I can't seem to figure out how to format it here in this box.

Answer (score 1):

`value` takes any string you give it and prints it literally. Try putting this snippet just below your input:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('newSubscription').value = getMaterials();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured that's what value did, but then things like value="<?php echo $bannerAd;?>" work just fine and I'm not sure why. Your solution worked well enough, but there's still a problem that I'm thinking must be on my end.

Comment: The reason why is that PHP is processed on the server. Javascript is processed on the client side. The browser does not allow you to put a script tag as the attribute value of a HTML tag. It's really important to understand the lifecycle of a web page when server-side and client-side code is involved.

Comment: Your browser never sees the PHP code. The whole `<?php echo $bannerAd; ?>` will be replaced with the actual value of `$bannerAd` *before* the browser gets involved. All the browser sees is `value="the_value_of_bannerAd"`, i.e. no tags, just plain text.

Comment: Thanks. That may help explain why my javascript global variables aren't persisting over from the php page that sets them to this page, which gets them? I have one central .js file between the two .php pages and I'm attempting to grab the global js variables between them without actually "passing" anything between pages.